# Java post request to Aruba hosting fails

Tags: java, php, http, post, request

I'm having a big trouble due to this problem.
I can't get POST data in my PHP API from a java client.
I'm having this problem only with Aruba hosting and not in local development or other hosting sites

this is the java request:

```
urlParameters = "name=Jack";
    byte[] postData = urlParameters.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    try {

        URL myurl = new URL(url);
        con = (HttpURLConnection) myurl.openConnection();

        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Java client");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postData.length));
        try (DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream())) {
            wr.write(postData);
        }

        StringBuilder content;

        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()))) {

            String line;
            content = new StringBuilder();

            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                content.append(line);
                content.append(System.lineSeparator());
            }
        }

        System.out.println(content.toString());

    }catch(MalformedURLException e){
        System.out.println("Error "+e);
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Error "+e);
      }
    finally {

        con.disconnect();
    }
```

Also in PHP i get:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')  false
$entityBody = file_get_contents('php://input');  empty string
```

I also tried also changing php version but nothing...
Thanks for help!

Using Wireshark I got this. I'm not an expert, but I think that the request is redirected by a proxy and becomes GET

[image]

ok I found another clue
Even with a html form it doesn't work but only if I use the full site path

```
<form method="POST" action="http://example.com/php/api.php"> doesn't work
<form method="POST" action="/php/api.php"> work
```

Now I think that is a permission problem, but I don't know what..

Comment: Does it work through a browser?

Comment: Yes I've got a page with a POST form and it works.

Comment: I would suggest using a network-monitoring tool (such as Wireshark) and compare the differences between the two requests.  If that doesn't clarify what you need to do, then please [edit] your question with the differences you find.

Comment: Thanks for suggest, I added the wireshark report

Comment: Here's what you need to do: (1) Look at the POST request that comes from your browser, (2) Look at the POST request that comes from Java, (3) Find the differences, (4) Include the differences in your question.  Without these differences, we cannot help you.

Comment: I think I've some permission problem, chack the edit if you can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using address url in the following format "**www.exemple.com/page.php**" instead of "**http://exemple.com/page.php**" or "**https://exemple.com/page.php**". Maybe due to a provider DNS settings